# Facebook HTTP Error 500 - Error during Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-500, capstone

So we created a web application for our project that uses facebook and gmail to log in. Gmail log in already works but the facebook log in keeps on having http error 500. We have tried it on different devices and different browsers and it keeps on showing the error message.

Comment: _"It haves a different error message"_ - and we are supposed to successfully _guess_ which one that might be now ...? Please provide a minimum of actually _useful_ information, if you want our help. [ask] has hints.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue lies on their end.

When a server encounters an unexpected problem preventing it from fulfilling a request, it responds with a 5xx status code. [See more](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-500-internal-server-error)

Specifically, the 500 Internal Server Error indicates such an issue.

On the other hand, if the response had a 4xx status code, the fault would be attributed to the requester. For instance, a 404 response occurs when a resource doesn’t exist. In this case, it appears that there’s an issue with their server.